# Alternate of package org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer in Spring 5.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

I am using package org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer in my Spring 4.3.25 for logging purpose. Now I am upgrading my spring version to 5.1.5 but there is no Log4jWebConfigurer class in spring-web. Do anybody know what alternate step I can take to resolve this ?

I am getting this error.

```
 BootstrapListener.java:[6,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Log4jWebConfigurer
[ERROR]   location: package org.springframework.web.util
```