# Any alternative package for org.springframework.util.log4jconfigurer in spring 5

Tags: java

I saw some the stackoverflow as log4jconfigurer are deprecated from spring 5 and not able to use more.

How to declare my custom class which is extended with `log4jwebconfigurer` having `log4jconfigurer.initloggging()`
And `REFRESH_INTERVAL_PARAM`?

```
Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(location);
String intervalString = servletContext.getInitParameter(REFRESH_INTERVAL_PARAM);
```

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59746441/alternate-of-package-org-springframework-web-util-log4jwebconfigurer-in-spring-5